# how to display text from file within JPanel?

Tags: java, jpanel

I have difficulties in displaying the text in JPanel. The question is do I have to use JLabel to display the text, or there is any other way to do so?  It seems like that's what most of the tutorials are telling me, I'm just not sure.

The code looks like this:

```
public class WhatToDo extends JFrame{

    public void aboutus(){

          try{
                //open the file
                FileInputStream inMessage = new FileInputStream("aboutus.txt");
                // Get the object of DataInputStream
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inMessage);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                //Read File Line By Line
                    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                        // Print the content on the console
                        System.out.println (strLine);
                    }
                    //Close the input stream
                    in.close();


        Container con = getContentPane();

        con.setLayout(null);
        ImageIcon imh1 = new ImageIcon("img/aboutus.png");
        setSize(imh1.getIconWidth(), imh1.getIconHeight());
        JPanel panelBgImg = new JPanel()
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
            {
                Image img = new ImageIcon("img/aboutus.png").getImage();
                Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
                setPreferredSize(size);
                setMinimumSize(size);
                setMaximumSize(size);
                setSize(size);
                setLayout(null);
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            } 
        };

        Container pane = getContentPane();

        JPanel back = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        back.add(new AboutUsBack(null));
        back.setBounds(1170, 665, 83, 85);  
        back.setBackground(new Color(118, 122, 117, 0));
        pane.add(back);

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        content.setToolTipText(strLine);
        content.setForeground(Color.red);
        content.setBounds(570, 165, 583, 85);   
        content.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 14));     
        pane.add(content);

        con.add(panelBgImg);
        panelBgImg.setBounds(0, 0, imh1.getIconWidth(), imh1.getIconHeight());

        setUndecorated(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

          }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }

    }
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I'd use a JTextPane in read-only mode. It's really easy, cares about flow and word wraps, and you can include HTML or RTF formatting and/or graphics if you want.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, While you don't **have** to use JLabel, this is the most fitting component to display text that no one should edit. Regarding your problem, it seems that you assign `strLine` only one line when you read it, I think it would be better if you add another variable to store that full `String` :

```
String strLine;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      // Print the content on the console
      System.out.println (strLine);
      sb.append(strLine);
}
```

And display it later (I assume in content panel):

```
JPanel content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JLabel info_from_file = new JLabel(sb.toString());
content.add(info_from_file);
content.setToolTipText(strLine);
content.setForeground(Color.red);
....
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works. however, what should I do to make it display line by line? Instead of just one long line?

Comment: look over here: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JLabel.html

Answer (score 1):

I think if you replace:

```
sb.append(strLine);
```

with:

```
sb.append(strLine+"/n");
```

you'll create a new line for every inputted line of text.That should fix the single line issue.

Comment: A component like `JTextArea` will wrap if configured to do so.  `JLabel` will only wrap if HTML formatting is used - new line characters are ignored.  ..And `/n` is not a new line character on *any* platform.  Try `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead.